# Removing Multiple Layers With Same Name in Layer Selection

Tags: qgis, layers, qgis-processing

For some of my QGIS projects, when I select a layer in a Processing Toolbox dialog I find multiple entries for some of my layers, as shown below:

[image: toolbox dialog with multiple layers]

There is one layer named "point," and one named "route" in my layer panel (both from Postgis tables), but multiple versions of both layers show up in the example toolbox dialog I opened. The duplicated layers all produce the same results.

I am using QGIS 3.10.4, and Postgresql 12.5 with PostGIS 3.0.0, on Pop!_OS 20.04.

Does anyone know what's gone wrong? Is there some way of removing the extra layers? I saw a similar question [asked here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330327/multiple-entries-of-same-layer-in-geopackage) but the layers in that case were coming from a geopackage file, and I'm not sure how the suggested answers might apply.

Comment: Seems a bug but you do not use the latest 3.10 series e.g `3.10.14` (released january 2021). Also 3.10 is not longer the current LTR. It's the 3.16 (see roadmap https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/roadmap.html). Upgrade (at least to latest 3.10) and make us a feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that these are "orphan" layers, ones that do not show up in the Layer Legend. I can create one pretty reliably by previewing a table in the DB Manager.

Upgrading to the latest LTR may be the best long term solution, but for now I can get rid of these layers from the Python Console by running:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject
layers_legend =  QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayerIds()
layers_all = [ l for l in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values() if l.id() not in layers_legend ]
for l in layers_all:
        print(l.name(), l.id())
        QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayers( [l.id()] )
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug and the cause is: every time you open a tool (Extract Layer Extent for example) the layers list will add up instead of getting refreshed.

The easiest solution is to upgrade to a stable release (3.16 at this time) or downgrade to some. Good luck.